"He nods for William to continue"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 20)

William, the chorister, is telling the story and background of Allegri's 'Miserere'


'In the old days, the 'Miserere' was only sung in the Sistine Chapel in Rome. The Pope wouldn't let it be sung anywhere else. . . . Anyone who tried to copy it or perform it somewhere else was thrown out of the Catholic Church.' He glances at Mr. Hawthorn (the teacher), wondering if he's telling the right version (of the stories that are connected with the history of Allegri's Miserere). He nods for William to continue. 'In those days. . .

I take 'for' to mean 'at' in this context, but I can't find any entry. Does the meaning of 'He nods for William' differ from 'He nods at William'?

Does this answer your question? "She nods for him to open the box full of butter biscuits" What makes you think the same construction from the same author in the same book might mean something different?

Compare: "The emperor gestures for the gladiators to begin" or "The emperor motions for the ambassador to sit down."  A "nod" is a  gesture that reveals the nodder's intent or wish. It can be used just like the verbs "gesture"  or "motion" or "signal" or "call".  Such verbs can be complemented with "for {someone} to {do something}".

The complement of for is not William but William to continue. The sentence means the same thing as *He nods to William to communicate the message that he, William, should continue."
